# Random order with Entity Framework Core - bug or wrong use?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

I have observed a strange behavior when using .Include() in combination with a random order:

In my project I created two tables: 'Product' and 'ProductImage' which are related by a navigation property (= foreign key in the database). A product can have a related product image - but there are also products without images.

Let's say I want to load the top 10 products that have a related product image (ordered by a 'CreationTime' (datetime) column):

```
Context
    .Product
    .Include(p => p.ProductImage)
    .Where(p => p.ProductImage.Any())
    .OrderBy(p => p.CreationTime)
    .Take(10)
    .ToListAsync()
```

This works fine and as expected. However when I change the order to

```
.OrderBy(p => Guid.NewGuid())
```

to randomly get ten products with images I indeed get 10 product entities but without related images.

At first I thought the .Include() was somehow removed because EF core "thinks" the related data is not needed (which is a feature actually) - so I looked into the queries with SQL Server Profiler:

I observed that EF Core constructed a query to load 10 rows in Product (with a correct WHERE clause to only select products with images) and a query to load 10 rows in ProductImage.
But the problem is that EF core split the Product.Include(p => p.ProductImage) into two seperate SELECTs - each with its own ORDER clause. And since I gave a random order each of these SELECTs has its own "ORDER BY NEWID()".

So at the end the products that were loaded didn't belong to the 10 product images that were loaded (at least with a great probability if more than ten products exist in the database).

So my question is: Do I use EF Core wrong at this point - or is this really something that should work (and I should report it somehow)?  Thank you very much!